# I lost 2 reputation, but there's no reason given... Why?

Tags: support, reputation

[image: Lose]

Why does it show that? I don't believe that I posted or did anything on that day, so I should not have lost any reputation.

Comment: Someone could have downvoted you.

Comment: But if that had happened, it would have said something like this: http://puu.sh/Pjqo (but it would have been bad)

Comment: The post could have been deleted afterwards

Comment: @soandos You get any lost reputation back if the post is deleted.

Comment: @iglvzx but it might not get wiped from that listing

Comment: None of my posts or answers have been deleted, but one has been closed.

Comment: 3 of your questions have been deleted. 1 of your answer has been deleted. Click on "show removed posts" at the bottom of the reputation tab to show this deleted post. // @iglvzx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `-2` is **usually** linked to receiving a downvote on your question or post.

I searched your questions and answers for downvotes and only found one:

> [image: downvote]

## However,

This is not the reason why you lost `2` reputation points. As [**@sathya**](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5355/i-lost-2-reputation-but-theres-no-reason-given-why#comment13976_5355) mentioned above, the `-2` is linked to one of your deleted answers:

> 3 of your questions have been deleted. 1 of your answer has been deleted. Click on **"show removed posts"** at the bottom of the reputation tab to show this deleted post.

Comment: Thanks for that. One question, though... How did you get it to show upvotes over downvotes, instead of just the total score?

Comment: @chipperyman573 you need at least 1000 rep to do that

Comment: ONE THOUSAND REP? Ohmygosh... Wow. Well, I'm 1/10th of the way there!

Comment: it's not a bug.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as the [timeline](http://superuser.com/posts/451221/timeline) to the question shows the downvote happened on July 29.

Comment: @DanielBeck Whoa. How long have we had this timeline feature? That's the first time I've seen it. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: There's a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) that adds the timeline link to the close/delete/link line.

Comment: I see my name in that screenshot. :3